# Image upload using python, cgi.FieldStorage() is empty

Tags: ajax, python-3.x

I am trying to upload image using ajax call to python script but cgi.FieldStorage() is empty, please suggest what am I doing wrong, any help is appreciated.

HTML code

```
<form id="imgform" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div style="display: inline-block;">
        <img style="width:150px;" id="bookimg" src="#" alt="" name="bookimg" />
        <input type="file" name="imginp" id="imgInp"/>
    </div>
    <div style="display: inline-block;">
        <input id="upload" type="button" value="Upload" />
    </div>
    <img src="images/loading.gif" id="busy_wait" alt="busy wait icon" />  
</form>
```

JS code

```
$("#upload").on('click', function(){
        var imgformdata = $("#imgform").serialize();
        $.post("python/processimage.py", imgformdata, function(response){
                response=$.trim(response);
                if(response == "invalidsession"){
                    window.location = 'logout.php';
                }else if(response == "ok"){
                    $(".imgdiag").html(response);
                }else{
                    $('#imguptext').text(response);
                }
            });
    });
```

Python code

```
#!C:\....\python.exe
import cgi, os
import cgitb; cgitb.enable()
form = cgi.FieldStorage()

# A nested FieldStorage instance holds the file
if len(form) > 0:
    fileitem = form["imginp"]

from PIL import Image, ImageFilter
print("Content-Type: text/html")
print()
print("<html><head><title>Python</title></head><body>")
print("<h5>"+str(len(form))+"</h5>")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed javascript and it is working fine -

```
$("#imgform").on('submit',function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url: "python/processimage.py", // Url to which the request is send
            type: "POST",             // Type of request to be send, called as method
            data: new FormData(this), // Data sent to server, a set of key/value pairs (i.e. form fields and values)
            contentType: false,       // The content type used when sending data to the server.
            cache: false,             // To unable request pages to be cached
            processData:false,        // To send DOMDocument or non processed data file it is set to false
            success: function(data)   // A function to be called if request succeeds
            {
                $(".imgdiag").html(data);
            }
        });
    });
```